# ActiveRecord: Read Only Model based on Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have worked with Postgres views in the past to model derived representation of data.

Overwriting ActiveRecord's [`readonly?`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Core/readonly%3F) helps with implementing that.

Unfortunately when used to heavily views have the downside of making schema changes very hard.

So I wonder if there is a way to assign an arbitrary query to a model and treat it like a table?

EDIT: Sorry I should have been more clear:

What I'd like is to do something like "Give me all users left joined with their comments" through a model called "UserWithComments". I know that this particular example could easily be achieved by using ActiveRecords DSL via `User.includes(:comments)` or similar.

If the query gets more complex the ActiveRecord DSL hits its limits so I could just create a view with my SQL and then use a readonly model that references the view. There are circumstances where creating a view is not feasible so I was wondering way to have a model called `UserWithComments` which is not linked to a table or view but instead has some kind of config option with an SQL like `select <attributes> from users u left join comments c on c.user_id = u.id`

Comment: What do you mean make a query read only? Users can only make changes to the data if you provide the functionality to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but I have used views this way:

Create your view in the DB. I am using an example called gear_alerts. Then in Rails create a model called `gear_alert.rb`:

```
class GearAlert < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :id
 
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_tags, through: :user
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :deactivated, -> {where(active: false) }

  def readonly?
    true
  end
end
```

as you can see, since views present themselves as tables normal ActiveRecord stores, you can treat it as such in a read-only context. I like views for when I am using complex table joins that have to be manipulated heavily before going to the presentation layer. Leaving it all for the browser to render can really slow things down. Maintaining views can be a pain. So I highly recommend the Scenic gem https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic as it lets you easily modify views from the rails migration tool while also giving you history of how the view has been modified over time.